# How to split column into rows Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, split

I have a table which I need two columns split into rows

eg: Table name : MY_TABLE_FILE

```
ref_no  cus_no  amount                              date
AA1      123    325000,200000,317085,2657915        20190522,20190405,20190402,20190322
AA2      265    1000000,1500000                     20190125,20190102
AA3      457    475000                              20190101
```

Output expected

```
ref_no  cus_no  amount            date
AA1      123    325000            20190522
AA1      123    200000            20190405
AA1      123    317085            20190402
AA1      123    2657915           20190322
AA2      265    1000000           20190125
AA2      265    1500000           20190102
AA3      457    475000            20190101
```

Code which i tried

```
SELECT ref_no,cus_no,
trim(regexp_substr(amount, '[^,]+',1,LEVEL)),
trim(regexp_substr(date, '[^,]+', 1,LEVEL))
FROM MY_TABLE_FILE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(amount, ',')+1
```

but i'm not get the output, 
Appreciate if you could help with the code

Comment: Use Distinct command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=339fc9427bfa282de757c41652f0901a)**

```
SELECT distinct ref_no, cus_no, 
       trim(regexp_substr(amount, '[^,]+', 1, level)) amount, 
       trim(regexp_substr(dater, '[^,]+', 1, level)) dater
FROM (SELECT ref_no,cus_no, amount,dater FROM TAB) t
CONNECT BY instr(amount, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0  
ORDER BY ref_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
SQL> with my_table_file (ref_no, cus_no, amount, cdate) as
  2    (select 'AA1', 123, '325000,200000,317085,2657915',
  3                        '20190522,20190405,20190402,20190322'
  4     from dual union all
  5     select 'AA2', 265, '1000000,1500000',
  6                        '20190125,20190102'
  7     from dual
  8    )
  9  select ref_no,
 10         cus_no,
 11         regexp_substr(amount, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) amount,
 12         regexp_substr(cdate , '[^,]+', 1, column_value) cdate
 13  from my_table_file cross join
 14       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 15                           connect by level <= regexp_count(amount, ',') + 1
 16                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 17  order by ref_no, cus_no, column_value;

REF     CUS_NO AMOUNT     CDATE
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
AA1        123 325000     20190522
AA1        123 200000     20190405
AA1        123 317085     20190402
AA1        123 2657915    20190322
AA2        265 1000000    20190125
AA2        265 1500000    20190102

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If `amount` and `cdate` column don't have same number of values, you can expect problems. If they do, then why do you store multiple values into one column? Read about *normalization* and - if possible - change data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() is not null 
AND PRIOR ref_no = ref_no
```

part depending on hierarchical logic :

```
SELECT ref_no, cus_no,
       trim(regexp_substr(amount, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) as amount,
       trim(regexp_substr("date", '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) as "date"
  FROM MY_TABLE_FILE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(amount, ',') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() is not null 
    AND PRIOR ref_no = ref_no     
ORDER BY ref_no, cus_no
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94bad1ed56981ec340b7dcf2a13206ae)</kbd>